# How to load a existing Texture using MTLRenderPassDescriptor

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am having a image in the asset. Then I am changing it to MTLTexture. I want to pass this texture to the shader function and append the texture and add the smudge feature to the passed texture using shader functions.

Currently I am passing the texture in MTLRenderPassDescriptor like below.

```
let renderPassWC = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
renderPassWC.colorAttachments[0].texture = ssTexture
renderPassWC.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .load
renderPassWC.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
```

When I edit the texture in Shader function like Moving the pixel of ssTexture to adjacent Pixel. [image] The movement don't stops. Because the operations I am doing in shader functions continuously operating in the appended Textures every draw cycle.

So I think rather than loadAction with load I feel clear will be a option but texture which passed become clear when I changed the code as below

```
renderPassWC.colorAttachments[0].texture = ssTexture
renderPassWC.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
renderPassWC.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0)
```

.Any possible way to pass the image texture with clear.

Comment: Can you show what you expected it to look like? Generally, the `colorAttachment` is an output texture, not an input texture. So if you don't want to modify the input texture, you shouldn't make it the texture in the texture attachment.

Comment: Input is like this https://imgur.com/gallery/OE61aS6 output should be like this https://imgur.com/gallery/s34GMFY ... Here I am doing it in Offscreen Rendering and Presenting it to Screen.

Comment: I am doing offscreen rendering in a texture and presenting that texture to the screen. like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511686/off-screen-rendering-metal