# With metal, how to draw on a off screen surface (an MTLTexture) from a background thread?

Tags: metal, metalkit

How to draw everything on a off screen surface (an MTLTexture) with Metal **from a background thread** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Off Screen Rendering Metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511686/off-screen-rendering-metal)

Comment: @trojanfoe what about background thread ?

Comment: What specific concerns do you have with issuing commands from a background thread? As long as you confine each command buffer to its own thread (command queues are intrinsically thread-safe), and are otherwise practicing good threading hygiene, everything should "just work." Have you observed this not to be the case?

Comment: @warrenm : so you mean that 2 background thread can do at the same time fcommandQueue.CommandBuffer ?

Comment: Yep. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandqueue): "Command queues are thread-safe and allow multiple outstanding command buffers to be encoded simultaneously." The order in which command buffers are submitted for execution is determined by the order in which you call `commit` on them, which can be controlled via a mechanism like dispatch queues or dispatch groups.