# The right way to make off-screen rendering in Metal

Tags: ios, macos, metal

I'm learning Metal and trying to implement post effect using out-screen rendering. For this purpose I draw my scene to the render target like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511686/off-screen-rendering-metal).

- Create MTLCommandBuffer
- Create MTLRenderCommandEncoder (set to the MTLRenderPassDescription my target texture)
- Write drawing commands to the encoder
- Finish encoding and commit the command buffer to the command queue

Then I want to draw my texture to the frame buffer (currentDrawable).

I suppose my texture is ready for drawing and I can use it. But when I draw the texture to the frame buffer I see trash. It looks like texture isn't ready. For fix it I call [waitUntilCompleted](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/1443039-waituntilcompleted?language=objc) for my out screen command buffer. It helps. 
But according to Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer):

> All command buffers sent to a single command queue are guaranteed to execute in the order in which the command buffers were enqueued.

So I expect that I can make it without calling blocking function `waitUntilCompleted`. But It doesn't work for me. See example:

```cs
var device = MTLDevice.SystemDefault;
var commandQueue = device.CreateCommandQueue();

//Create texture for renderTarget
var textDesc = MTLTextureDescriptor.CreateTexture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat, Width, Height, 1);
textDesc.Usage = MTLTextureUsage.RenderTarget | MTLTextureUsage.ShaderRead;
textDesc.StorageMode = MTLStorageMode.Private;
IMTLTexture texture = device.CreateTexture(textDesc);

var textPassDesc = new MTLRenderPassDescriptor();
textPassDesc.ColorAttachments[0].LoadAction = MTLLoadAction.Clear;
textPassDesc.ColorAttachments[0].StoreAction = MTLStoreAction.Store;
textPassDesc.ColorAttachments[0].Texture = texture;

var commandBuffer = commandQueue.CommandBuffer();
var commandEncoder = commandBuffer.CreateRenderCommandEncoder(textPassDesc);

//Drawing scene. I guess It's not interesting now
{
...
}

//Finish command
commandEncoder.EndEncoding();
commandBuffer.Commit();
//The main goal of the question, can I escape this calling ? 
commandBuffer.WaitUntilCompleted();

var finalPassDesc = MTKView.CurrentRenderPassDescriptor;
commandBuffer = commandQueue.CommandBuffer();
commandEncoder = commandBuffer.CreateRenderCommandEncoder(finalPassDesc);

//Drawing the frame with texture
{
commandEncoder.SetFragmentTexture(texture, 0);
commandEncoder.SetFragmentSamplerState(defaultSamplerState, 0);
...
}
commandEncoder.EndEncoding();
commandBuffer.PresentDrawable(MTKView.CurrentDrawable);
commandBuffer.Commit();
```

What's the right way to make off-screen rendering using metal?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I'm working with Xamarin bindings using C#. Can I post C# code?

Comment: of course, go ahead.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Added code sample

Comment: You shouldn't need to wait on the first command buffer to complete before encoding the pass that renders to the screen. You shouldn't even need to use a separate command buffer. I suspect something is going wrong in code that isn't shown here. Have you tried using GPU Frame Capture in Xcode to ensure everything looks like you expect?

Comment: @warrenm Sorry for waiting, I work with Xamaring Bindings (using visual studio)  and at the first sight It's very difficult to find how I can make GPU Frame Capture. But I found out workaround and made it. My problem was using the same dataBuffer for different renderTargets. Thanks.